# TextBox trigger to clear Text using a style

Tags: wpf, text, triggers, textbox

First, let me say I've been working with WPF for about a week. I want to style a TextBox so that when it is disable, it is cleared. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756683/wpf-textbox-trigger-to-clear-text) article explained how to do it, however I'm confused on how to set the generic style as a resource so that every TextBox can bind to a different property without repeating the style for each TextBox.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="style1">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{What do I really put here?}" /> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" /> 
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style> 
    </Window.Resources>
```

....

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource style1}" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `Text` property like that. Setting the `Text` property explicitly on any `TextBox` that has that style will override the `Text` setter in the trigger (like you noticed).

If you only need the `TextBox` to be cleared and not the property it is binding to, then a workaround is to use an attached property (or `Tag`) for the text which you bind `Text` to in the `Style`.
Example..

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="style1">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                            Path=Tag}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then a `TextBox` can use this `Style` like

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource style1}" Tag="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```